# Convert elements in ONE list to keys and values in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to convert a list to a dictionary as shown below. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

list = ["1/a", "2/b", "3/c"]

dict = {"1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"}

Comment: Yes it is possible, split('/') each item in the list first, then you have key:value, now add it to list, it is the hint

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible.

First, you can split an element of the list with `e.split("/")`, which will give a list for example `splitted = ["1", "a"]`.
You can assign the first element to the key and the second to the value:

```
k = splitted[0]
v = splitted[1]
```

or another way to express that:

```
k,v = splitted
```

Then you can iterate over your list to build your dict, so if we wrap this up (you should not call a list `list` because `list` is a type and an already existing identifier:

```
d = {}
for e in elements:
     k,v = e.split("/")
     d[k] = v
```

You can also do that in one line with a dict comprehension:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in [e.split("/") for e in elements]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

If you want to have everything after the '/' (i.e. 2nd char), you can do:

`dict = {c[0]:c[2:] for c in list}`

If you want to have everything after the '/' (but may not be the 2nd char), you can do:

`dict = {c[0]:c.split('/')[1] for c in list}`

It really dependes on the input you have and what output you want

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
lista = ["1/a", "2/b", "3/c"]
new_dict = {}
for val in lista:    
    new_dict.update({val[0]:val[2]})
print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list = ["1as/aasc", "2sa/bef", "3edc/cadeef"]
dict = {i.split('/')[0]:i.split('/')[1] for i in list}
```

Answer will be

```
{'1as': 'aasc', '2sa': 'bef', '3edc': 'cadeef'}
```

I have given a different test case. Hope this will answer your question.